# Google Structured Data Testing Tool - organization error seems to contradict their guidlines

Tags: google, microdata, rich-snippets, markup, google-rich-snippets-tool

Google Structured Data Testing Tool is giving this error:

> Error: This information will not appear as a rich snippet in search
>   results, because it seems to describe an organization. Google does not
>   currently display organization information in rich snippets

Yet the warning links to this page: [Rich snippets - Organizations](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146861?hl=en) where it says:

> Organization information (for example, details about a business such
>   as a restaurant or attraction) that is marked up in the body of a web
>   page can help Google understand location information in reviews or
>   events. It can also be displayed on a Place Page—a web page that
>   organizes all relevant information about a place

So in the error message Google is saying they don't support Organizations, but then on the help page they seem to be saying they do support it?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I have no experience with it, but couldn’t it be the case that the error talks about Google Search SERPs, while the Organization Rich Snippet is used on "Place Pages" only?

Comment: I agree with @Unor. As well, know that while Google does use and recognize the markup within a page rather well and does use some for their SERPs, it has not yet fully developed all of the code that people seem to expect at this point. For Google and Bing, this is a work in progress though they are working on it rather quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max, Google does support structured data for Organization markups, but they don't support rich snippets for the type.  If you change schema.org/Organization to schema.org/LocalBusiness in your markup, you'll see the testing tool results change and the rich snippets displaying.  So the error message you're seeing is in regards to rich snippets, not the structured data itself.

It is rather unusual, because Google does display rich snippets for extensions of schema.org/Organization, such as LocalBusiness, Restaurant, etc.  They just don't support rich snippets for the Organization type.  Strange, but it is what it is.

Comment: Thanks, not particularly clear guidance from Google.